# authlogic session creation fails when used in combination with authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic, basic-authentication

I recently wanted to deploy my Rails app on heroku but wanted to shield it from the outside world until I had tested it on the heroku itself.  In order to shield it I have used authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic.  However after having passed through the basic authentication and wanting to login (login system using authlogic) I find that authlogic doesn't remember a session (e.g. current_user == nil).

Without the authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic before_filter the authlogic sessions work fine.

Does anybody know why this is and how to make the two work together?

Thanks in advance.

PS: Just to be clear, my goal is **not** to be able to use authlogic users with authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic.

PPS: I use Rails 3 and git://github.com/odorcicd/authlogic.git

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm having this issue also!  I'm going to try and look into it to see if I can come up with anything...

EDIT: The fix is to disallow HTTP basic auth on your Authlogic session...

```
class UserSession < Authlogic::Session::Base
    allow_http_basic_auth false
end
```

I'm pretty sure that this is a bug in Authlogic. The problem is this method:

```
Authlogic::Session::HttpAuth::InstanceMethods#allow_http_basic_auth?
```

which returns true when HTTP Basic is being used, even elsewhere in your application.

Comment: Thanks!  I tried your fix and it worked like a charm.  Maybe we should indeed submit a bug report.